# Drawing NSView and adding subviews

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to make a custom NSView subclass. It does some drawing inside drawRect method. It also needs to have subviews(a couple of NSTextField s). So my question is should I add these NSTextFields inside of drawRect method or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely elsewhere.  `-drawRect` should only do drawing, nothing else.

If you are creating the view programatically, you can override the `-initWithFrame` method, call `[super initWithFrame:frame]` and then add your subviews there.

If the view is in an xib file, then you can create the subviews in `-awakeFromNib`. Or simply add them in the nib itself in Interface Builder.

Comment: In what way did that deserve a down vote?  Someone with a grudge?